# curl to python requests conversion

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, dropbox

I'm working with Dropbox's python API, trying to convert the following curl command to Python Requests:

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download \
        --header "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
        --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/Homework/math/Prime_Numbers.txt\"}"
```

My translation so far:

```
downloadHeader={"Authorization: " + authorization}

downloadURL = "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download"

downloadPayload = {"Dropbox-API-Arg": {"path": "/" + dbPATH}}

downloadResponse = requests.post(downloadURL, data=json.dumps(downloadPayload), headers=downloadHeader)
```

However, when I run this I get the following error:

> for header in headers.items():
>       AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'

Can anyone give me some feedback?  I'm confident about my authorization value because it's working in a separate request which I'm copy and pasting below:

```
MDlink = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/get_shared_link_metadata"
authorization = "Bearer " + ACCESS_TOKEN
headers={"Content-Type":"application/json", "Authorization": authorization}
payload = {"url": imageLink}
response = requests.request("POST", MDlink, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I suggest you should use any debugging web proxy, like:

[mitmproxy, (pythonic), console/webbased, free](http://mitmproxy.org)

[the fiddler, (win), GUI, free](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

[charles debugging proxy, (win/java), GUI, commercial](https://www.charlesproxy.com)

all of them supports binary serialized traffic (i.e. AMF),
they simply turn your http(s) reversing tasks into pleasure :)

Comment: I redacted it from the question and answer, but for the sake of security, you should disable that access token, since it was posted publicly. You can do so by revoking access to the app entirely, if the access token is for your account, here:

https://www.dropbox.com/account/security

Or, you can disable just this access token using the API:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#auth-token-revoke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this

```
downloadHeader={"Authorization: " + authorization}
```

To be

```
downloadHeader={"Authorization": authorization}
```

Or more precisely

```
downloadHeader={"Authorization": "Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>"}
```

Explanation:

```
{1} # this is a set. It has no .items()
{1: 1} # this is a dict. You can call .items()
```